# Matching Values in different ranges

Tags: excel

In one worksheet I have:

`List of Overseas Office Company A       Hot Country        Cold Country

   Country A                              Country E          Country B
   Country B                              Country F          Country C
   Country C                              Country Y          Country N
   Country D                              Country A          Country W`

I have Overseas Office = Range1; Hot Country = Range2 and Cold Country = Range3

In a separate worksheet I have:

`Company    Hot Country Office  Cold Country Office`

As I list companies, I need a formula that will check Range1 against Range2 and Range 3. So for Company A the result would be:

`Company   Hot Country Office  Cold Country Office
A               TRUE                TRUE`

Reason for the above is that Company A has offices in Countries A, B, C and D, and Country A is a Hot Country and Countries B and C are Cold Countries.

I've tried: `=COUNTIF(Range1, Range2) + COUNTIF(Range1, Range3) >=1`, however it does not appear this works each time.

Comment: `=countif(companyRange, Range2) + countif(companyRange, Range3) >= 1` should work just fine

Comment: I've tried this and the values coming out don't appear to be correct; I get FALSE where I know it should be TRUE because I compare the Ranges visually

Comment: The formula is correct. Your data is probably bad. Make sure there are no trailing spaces or tabs behind your data. Split that `countif()` up into to separate formulas and determine which range it is that isn't working and clean your data.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working, I've split out the formula into separate columns, checked the underlying data (lists are not too long, I am typing them out so no hidden tabs or spaces) and it doesn't seem to provide the correct result

Comment: I've set up simple dummy Ranges: test[a,b,c]; test1[b,c,d]; test2[c,d,e] and running formula =COUNTIF(test, test1)>=1 provides a FALSE, which is incorrect because b and c both appear in "test" and "test1"

Comment: Are you doing wildcard searching here? Like... Do you want to find the string "Company" in a range where one of the cells in the range says "This is a Company" and you want it to return true? That's a very different question.

Comment: So column 4 would be {TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}?

Comment: You need to compare one at a time, `=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)+COUNTIF(C:C,A1)>0`

Answer (score 0):

It appears the following formula works:

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Range1, Range2))>=1`